# Disabling Application Internet Connectivity w/ out VPN Running

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, internet-connection

Whats the easiest way in Windows to make it so an application can't access the internet through my internet connection but will work when I am connect thru a VPN.

Comment: To clarify, once you are om the VPN, the application should be able to reach the internet, or just the remote network?

Answer (score 0):

Some of the better firewall applications provide the ability to distinguish between different networks and use different settings for each.

I would personally recommend [ZoneAlarm](http://www.zonealarm.com/security/en-us/zonealarm-pc-security-free-firewall.htm) which has a per-application and per-network firewall setting.